# Should putting clearly written questions on hold be acceptable?

Tags: discussion

This question is clearly written. [How do I convert a string/decimal to IEEE-754 binary/hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979509/how-do-i-convert-a-string-decimal-to-ieee-754-binary-hex) Language agnostic are allowed on stack overflow and the C library is considered to be part of the C++ library. In my opinion it is fine for a question to accept answers in multiple languages if answers in other languages could be considered as a duplicate.

Right now the question in question is clearly written with a duplicate (question on C) being closed as duplicate to that. However since both questions are closed it's impossible to add new answers (such as a implementation that does not require using float). Enough people thought it was clearly written enough to be reopened (which can be seen in the history) yet it was voted closed a second time because it's 'unclear'. It's pretty ridiculous that it's unclear. The question should have the tags edited if that is the problem but right now that's not what is being done.

Should putting clearly written questions on hold be acceptable? It seems like it's abusing the system to deal with other problems.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous meta post? Or if not an exact duplicate a greatly similar post? If so, should you delete the other post?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a break for a few days from meta. I know that you probably feel strongly on this point, but posting multiple poorly received questions about it is not the answer. I don't know what you seek to achieve.

Comment: The [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags are trolling us.

Answer (score 11):

Your argument hinges on whether the question was "clearly written". And the answer to that is essentially what you consider "clearly written".

On the one hand, even the first revision of the question seems clear as to its intent. You specifically mention that you have the number as a string, hence the "1.3". You specifically mention what the expected output of this process ought to be. And given the relationship between your stated input and output, the obvious idea (convert the string to an integer) is not what you were asking for, since it clearly would not produce the desired output from the example input.

So for me, the question was clear.

On the other hand... I shouldn't *have to* go though that last step. I happen to have a background where I would sometimes/frequently have to see floats in memory stored as bytes. As such, I have a pretty good idea when I'm looking at a `float` in hex. That's why I was able to make the inference I did. But I shouldn't *have to* have that background in order to understand your question.

And on the gripping hand, the question contains a lot of noise. See to me, the question *really* is, "how do I read the bits of an IEEE-754 BINARY32 value as an unsigned integer?" All of the rest of it is just fluff. You *know* how to convert a string into a `float` (and if you don't, Google it). You *know* how to convert an unsigned integer into a hexadecimal or decimal string (again, Google it if you don't). So all that's left is the part you don't know how to do: read the actual bytes of data stored in that floating-point value.

And I'm pretty sure we already have questions for doing such a conversion on this site.

So, should it be closed as unclear? Meh, probably not. It is however clearly a duplicate of any question that asks about performing byte-wise float-to-int conversions. And it's not even a very *good* duplicate, since most people wouldn't ask how to do this process when starting from a string (since again, people know how to turn strings into floats).

In my mind, that the question ought to be closed however is not in doubt. We can quibble over the right way to close it, but it still should be closed.

Comment: I would say I would have answered by converting to numeric first and then converting the memory representation of the number to a string. So I guess I dispute the assertion in this answer that he implicit requirement to not convert to numeric was “obvious”. To me it seems this is a practical question seeking practical results, and converting to numeric is the best, fastest, and easiest way to achieve that, including all the corner cases for the machine’s particular architecture which would make any other kind of answer a tutorial on “how does IEEE floating point representation work?”.

Comment: @DanBron: "*So I guess I dispute the assertion in this answer that he implicit requirement to not convert to numeric was “obvious”.*" ... since when was that a requirement? There is nothing in *any* revision of the question that suggests that the OP would disallow converting to a `float` or `double` first. I asserted no such thing in this answer. I asserted that converting the string "1.3" to the integer `1` would not be an answer.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted your answer. For the record, I have neither upvoted nor downvoted this answer (nor any other Q nor A in the entire system of posts about the Q in question).

Comment: "It is however clearly a duplicate of any question that asks about performing byte-wise float-to-int conversions" not exactly. Not all hardware uses IEEE-754 so bitwise float to int convention are not a complete solution. An algorithm converting a string to the bit representative would be which would not be an answer in 'duplicate' float to int convention answers.

Comment: @acidzombie24: "*Not all hardware uses IEEE-754 so bitwise float to int convention are not a complete solution.*" Funny; it was complete enough for you to *mark it accepted*. If you're confused about what is or is not a complete answer, that lends support to the "not clearly written" side. And if support for unusual architectures was a concern for you, you should have put it in your question.

Comment: @acidzombie24: And now I'm confused. The question we're discussing is *not that question*. So I don't know what that question has to do with this one.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Here's the thing. Either you need a solution that works even on implementations that don't support IEEE-754 float types, or you don't. And if you do have that need, then that really is a *different question* from the one most people have. And it's definitely a different question from what you asked for, since you did not state this as an explicit need.

Comment: @NicolBolas: **No. Here is the thing**. I didn't ask how to get bits out of a double and it shouldn't be treated as such. Just because that's **a** solution it doesn't mean the question is how do I get bits from a double. There is exactly zero reasons to close that question. It is not too broad, it isn't unclear. It hasn't been asked before (to my knowledge). No one (to my knowledge) is closing C++ questions on IO because C pretty much have that covered. You don't have to use FILE in C++ and you don't have to typecast/memcpy a double to get the solution. Period.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Questions get closed as duplicates all the time because while they seem different, they still ultimately resolve down to the same answer. If such approaches are inadequate for your needs, then your question needs to explain *how* they're inappropriate and therefore why it isn't a duplicate. To put it another way, if 99% of the answers to your question would be answered by another, then your question needs to explicitly state that you need the 1% solution (which you eventually did). Having that much answer overlap is indicative of a duplicate.

Comment: My needs isn't the point. The point is searching dozens of similar worded questions for one that explicitly says something you need that the others don't is a pain. There's no reason I have to search language-agnostic implementation to hope I find an implementation in C or C++ because every question in those languages are a duplicate of casting/memcpy float to int

Comment: @acidzombie24: "*My needs isn't the point.*" No, that *is the point*. You did not adequately express your needs. You need a solution that works directly from the string, without relying on the implementation's binary representation of floating-point values. That is a rare and *very specific* need, one which if not actually expressed will not be adequately met by answers. Also, people don't search for questions by tag. And there's no reason you *had to* use the language-agnostic tag; that was a choice you made yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You started with:

> This question is clearly written.

I agree that the English in the question is clear, but English has a truly annoying habit of often being ambiguous.  If I had run across it in the close vote queue, I likely would flagged it as too broad.

But I probably would have been wrong.  Let's look at the current definition:

#### *unclear what you're asking*:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

I would say the keyword here is *exactly*.

You gave one hint in how I was thinking when you said:

> However since both questions are closed it's impossible to add new answers **(such as a implementation that does not require using float)**.

If I had taken the time neccesary to write up an answer using this method, and then found, it wasn't the answer you were expecting, it would have been a bit disappointing, even if the answer was satisfiying to create.

Also, the accepted answer required an edit to start from a string (author missed that detail (question too broad?)) and another answer explicitly asked:

> Let me know if I interpreted your question properly.

I think the question could be reasonable interpreted as not being entirely clear.

#### An answer to this question?

With that out of the way, let me try to address your question:

> Should putting clearly written questions on hold be acceptable?  It seems like it's abusing the system to deal with other problems.

Stackoverflow is system trying to strike a balance somewhere between top down authority and anarchy.  I think it generally does a pretty good job.  But anytime you have a large group of individuals, there are going to be disagreements.  The five votes to close/reopen is a (generally successful) attempt to allow a large group of individuals to come a consensus, but it certainly will not always work.

A couple of key words:

> *Acceptable* - Adequate to satisfy a need, requirement, or standard; satisfactory.

I don't think, given the distributed nature of moderation here, and the inevitable disagreement that will arise within a group of individuals, that the voting system does satisfy a need, even with one's (hopefully) occasional disagreement with results.

> *Abuse* - To use wrongly or improperly

I think to know if there was abuse here, would require knowing the unknown, ie: What was the close voters motivation.  The inability to know with any certainty this motivation means that it almost certainly needs to be ignored without a *lot* more data than one vote.  So I do not think there is anyway to know if the votes were some sort of abuse.

#### Muddled

So, putting a clearly question written on hold may not acceptable, but figuring out exactly what *clearly* and *acceptable* mean in this context is full of enough ambiguity, because there a humans involved, that I think the answer to your question is probably: yes it is acceptable.

Comment: >*"Also, the accepted answer required an edit to start from a string (author missed that detail (question too broad?)) and another answer explicitly asked: Let me know if I interpreted your question properly."* This is annoying me. If you look at the history every version of the question specifies string and just because one answer says let me know if I interpreted the question correctly does no mean he did not understand. He may have said it out of politeness or because he is suspicious using the native double and memcpy may not have been what I wanted (which was indeed ok). Absolutely clear